# Is 1D Barcode - code128 supported for iOS 7.1.2?

Tags: ios, passbook, wallet

When I download the .pkpass file from my iOS 7.1.2, with a coupon which has code128 barcode, am unable to download the pass. I get an error message as "Sorry, Your Pass cannot be installed to Passbook at this time"

Why am I getting this error? From which version is code128 barcode supported?

Any solution to this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Support for Code-128 Barcodes started with iOS 9.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/PassKit_Bundle/Chapters/TopLevel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012026-CH2-SW5

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a fallback barcode for devices running iOS8 and below.  Instead of using a `barcode` key with a single barcode dictionary, use a `barcodes` (note plural) key with an array of dictionaries that include at least one pre-iOS9 format.

See the Visual Appearance Keys in the Package format reference document. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/PassKit_Bundle/Chapters/TopLevel.html